# carousel renderscript make cards counterclockwise to scroll

Tags: java, android, carousel, renderscript

I need some help with the CarouselExample that can be checked out using this [link](http://code.google.com/p/android-ui-utils/downloads/detail?name=CarouselExample.zip). I want to make cards counterclockwise to scroll around the carousel. but I don't found a method in the Carousel.rs file.
 Please if someone has checked this example and knows how to help me, i would appreciate it. 
 like this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0ORaa3AfoB8SHBaX2U3elJSams/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

In CarouselController.java, I think you can set mFillDirection to CarouselRS.FILL_DIRECTION_CW.

Comment: First, thanks. However, according to the proposed changes after you, just opposite the filling order card, did not change the curvature and orientation of the card slot. My English is not so good, sorry.

Comment: Oh, I think that you would have to modify the way they are drawing things as well. Sorry, I don't actually have much experience on the graphics side of things.

Answer (score 0):

the CarouselExample is deprecated, since the renderscript UI/3d part can't be used anymore.

instead, google suggests using openGL.

Comment: about renderscript? i agree. wish there were better samples, tutorials and documentations.